# Generic and Custom redirects though htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a wordpress blog that was running on some old domain name and now I am migrating to a new domain name.

I am trying to setup a redirect from the old url to the new url.
But I want custom redirect for the homepage and a generic redirect for the pages for instance:

```
1. https://www.oldsite.com  --> 301 --> https://www.newsite.com/page1
2. https://www.oldsite.com/page2 --> 301 --> https://www.newsite.com/page2
3. https://www.oldsite.com/page3 --> 301 --> https://www.newsite.com/page3
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Note: By 301, I mean permanent redirect.

Comment: So you want `https://www.oldsite.com` to go to `https://www.newsite.com/page1` rather than `https://www.newsite.com/` directly?

Comment: Yes, you are right!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. 
Writing the answer so that some one else can get benefit.

```
# Custom Redirect For HomePage
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.newsite.com/page1/? [L,R=301]

#Generic Redirect for the entire website
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldsite.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

The sequence is important here, the custom redirects should be placed first and then the generic redirects for the domain.